# Is google location history accurate

Tags: google, geolocation, history

my girlfriend's location history show her places on different days that she swears she had not been to. I
s this info accurate

Answer (score 0):

It depends. It will be dependant on how you have your GPS Settings set.

One option gives precise mobile position. The other will fluctuate a bit to correspond with the cell phone tower the phone is pinging.

For example my phone on 4G will sometimes display my location is Orange City which is about 8 miles from where I actually am. But if I do a search to find my phone, it will show me as my actual location.

Comment: That's correct, although Google says that I'm more than 100km away from my real position.